# How to drag and drop the nodes from left tree to right tree as a copy not move

Tags: primeng

Hi i am using Angular 14 Version
I am Working on Prime Ng Drag and drop control, here i am facing some problems like, when i drag the node from left tree and drop it to the right tree that time dragged node is removing from the left tree.
How to prevent or retain the node even i am after doing drag and drop between the trees. Trying to drag our own items like, https://primefaces.org/primeng/tree/dragdrop
How can i do this? Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean this? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dragdrop, im not sure if i understand what you ask.

If you want items to keep their position after you refresh the page you will need some DB to remember their status,

however if you want dragged item to stay in the left tree after dragging you will need to change source code a little bit

```
drop(event) {
     if (this.draggedProduct) {
         let draggedProductIndex = this.findIndex(this.draggedProduct);
         this.selectedProducts = [...this.selectedProducts, this.draggedProduct];
    //   this.availableProducts = this.availableProducts.filter((val,i) => i!=draggedProductIndex);
         this.draggedProduct = null;
     }
 }
```

try to comment the filter line to prevent item to be deleted from left tree

Comment: No i am trying to drag our own items, trying this https://primefaces.org/primeng/tree/dragdrop.   when i drag the node from left tree and drop it to the right tree that time dragged node is removing from the left tree. How to prevent or retain the node even i am after doing drag and drop between the trees.

Comment: well i see two variants, you can remake the logic in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/dragdrop style but i would recomand you not to. You can implement function that load files from scratch after every drag so items in the "item tree" will always be there, its a workaround but should work just fine

Comment: My left tree is big other than reloading the files is there any other solution to prevent nodes?
In worst case, no other solution, then how to keep the expanded states?